# create json using Google Gson

Tags: java, json, jsp, jakarta-ee

I want make json

```
records":[ {"MON_PRIORITY":"","MON_ICR_ACCNO":"100000010010","MON_REPORT_DATE":"","MON_STATUS":"",
```

But my json is

```
   {"MON_PRIORITY":"","MON_ICR_ACCNO":"100000010010","MON_REPORT_DATE":"","MON_STATUS":"",
```

My jsp code is

```
HashMap  jsonRecordval = (HashMap) hshValues.get("jsonRecord");
String json="";
json = new Gson().toJson(jsonRecordval );
```

Thanks..

Comment: Always use generics while using collection APIs , Then your code will be more clean. let me know the key and value data types.

Answer (score 1):

What you're getting is the JSON produced by a Hashmap. e.g. `{"key":"value"}`. Breaking it down piece by what, your desired json is a representation of an object `{` with a records field `"records"` that contains an array `[` of the contents of your hashmap `{"key":"value"}`

To do that, it's easiest to create an object with instance variables corresponding to the fields to expected output. Something like

```
public class JsonRecords {
    private final List<HashMap> records = new ArrayList<>;

    public JsonRecords(HashMap recordsVal) {
        records.add(recordsVal);
    }

    //Getters and setters
}
```

Then use it to build your JSON

```
HashMap  jsonRecordval = (HashMap) hshValues.get("jsonRecord");
String json = new Gson().toJson(new JsonRecords(jsonRecordval));
```